# Neovim 0.5+ setup as Rust IDE

Tags: vimscript, neovim, lsp

So I am trying to set up neovim 0.5+ as a rust IDE.
I am following [this guide](https://sharksforarms.dev/posts/neovim-rust/).

Except, as shown in the guide, there is not completion even after doing `<c-x><c-o>`.

I have kept the config in `~/.config/nvim/ftplugin/rust.vim`.

My `rust.vim`:

```
call plug#begin('~/.config/nvim/plugged/rust')

" Collection of common configurations for the Nvim LSP client
Plug 'neovim/nvim-lspconfig'

" Completion framework
Plug 'hrsh7th/nvim-cmp'

" LSP completion source for nvim-cmp
Plug 'hrsh7th/cmp-nvim-lsp'

" syntax checking
Plug 'rust-lang/rust.vim'

" status bar
Plug 'vim-airline/vim-airline'

" Snippet completion source for nvim-cmp
Plug 'hrsh7th/cmp-vsnip'

" Other usefull completion sources
Plug 'hrsh7th/cmp-path'
Plug 'hrsh7th/cmp-buffer'

" See hrsh7th's other plugins for more completion sources!

" To enable more of the features of rust-analyzer, such as inlay hints and more!
Plug 'simrat39/rust-tools.nvim'

" Snippet engine
Plug 'hrsh7th/vim-vsnip'

" Fuzzy finder
" Optional
Plug 'nvim-lua/popup.nvim'
Plug 'nvim-lua/plenary.nvim'
Plug 'nvim-telescope/telescope.nvim'

" Color scheme used in the GIFs!
" Plug 'arcticicestudio/nord-vim'

call plug#end()

" Set completeopt to have a better completion experience
" :help completeopt
" menuone: popup even when there's only one match
" noinsert: Do not insert text until a selection is made
" noselect: Do not select, force user to select one from the menu
set completeopt=menuone,noinsert,noselect

" Avoid showing extra messages when using completion
set shortmess+=c

" Configure LSP through rust-tools.nvim plugin.
" rust-tools will configure and enable certain LSP features for us.
" See https://github.com/simrat39/rust-tools.nvim#configuration
lua <<EOF
local nvim_lsp = require'lspconfig'

local opts = {
    tools = { -- rust-tools options
        autoSetHints = true,
        hover_with_actions = true,
        inlay_hints = {
            show_parameter_hints = false,
            parameter_hints_prefix = "",
            other_hints_prefix = "",
        },
    },

    -- all the opts to send to nvim-lspconfig
    -- these override the defaults set by rust-tools.nvim
    -- see https://github.com/neovim/nvim-lspconfig/blob/master/doc/server_configurations.md#rust_analyzer
    server = {
        -- on_attach is a callback called when the language server attachs to the buffer
        -- on_attach = on_attach,
        settings = {
            -- to enable rust-analyzer settings visit:
            -- https://github.com/rust-analyzer/rust-analyzer/blob/master/docs/user/generated_config.adoc
            ["rust-analyzer"] = {
                -- enable clippy on save
                checkOnSave = {
                    command = "clippy"
                },
            }
        }
    },
}

require('rust-tools').setup(opts)
EOF

" Setup Completion
" See https://github.com/hrsh7th/nvim-cmp#basic-configuration
lua <<EOF
local cmp = require'cmp'
cmp.setup({
  -- Enable LSP snippets
  snippet = {
    expand = function(args)
        vim.fn["vsnip#anonymous"](args.body)
    end,
  },
  mapping = {
    ['<C-p>'] = cmp.mapping.select_prev_item(),
    ['<C-n>'] = cmp.mapping.select_next_item(),
    -- Add tab support
    ['<S-Tab>'] = cmp.mapping.select_prev_item(),
    ['<Tab>'] = cmp.mapping.select_next_item(),
    ['<C-d>'] = cmp.mapping.scroll_docs(-4),
    ['<C-f>'] = cmp.mapping.scroll_docs(4),
    ['<C-Space>'] = cmp.mapping.complete(),
    ['<C-e>'] = cmp.mapping.close(),
    ['<CR>'] = cmp.mapping.confirm({
      behavior = cmp.ConfirmBehavior.Insert,
      select = true,
    })
  },

  -- Installed sources
  sources = {
    { name = 'nvim_lsp' },
    { name = 'vsnip' },
    { name = 'path' },
    { name = 'buffer' },
  },
})
EOF

" Code navigation shortcuts
nnoremap <silent> <c-]> <cmd>lua vim.lsp.buf.definition()<CR>
nnoremap <silent> K     <cmd>lua vim.lsp.buf.hover()<CR>
nnoremap <silent> gD    <cmd>lua vim.lsp.buf.implementation()<CR>
nnoremap <silent> <c-k> <cmd>lua vim.lsp.buf.signature_help()<CR>
nnoremap <silent> 1gD   <cmd>lua vim.lsp.buf.type_definition()<CR>
nnoremap <silent> gr    <cmd>lua vim.lsp.buf.references()<CR>
nnoremap <silent> g0    <cmd>lua vim.lsp.buf.document_symbol()<CR>
nnoremap <silent> gW    <cmd>lua vim.lsp.buf.workspace_symbol()<CR>
nnoremap <silent> gd    <cmd>lua vim.lsp.buf.definition()<CR>

" have a fixed column for the diagnostics to appear in
" this removes the jitter when warnings/errors flow in
set signcolumn=yes

" Set updatetime for CursorHold
" 300ms of no cursor movement to trigger CursorHold
set updatetime=300

" Goto previous/next diagnostic warning/error
nnoremap <silent> g[ <cmd>lua vim.lsp.diagnostic.goto_prev()<CR>
nnoremap <silent> g] <cmd>lua vim.lsp.diagnostic.goto_next()<CR>

nnoremap <silent> ga    <cmd>lua vim.lsp.buf.code_action()<CR>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the guide is not explicit about it, those configuration snippets are meant to be added to the main NeoVim configuration file, at `~/.config/nvim/init.vim`, and not in a per-filetype file for Rust.

In particular, vim-plug configuration (the `Plug` statements) only work in `init.vim` (or the `.vimrc` file for Vim), since plug-ins are loaded in startup right after `init.vim`, so the runtime path is supposed to be set really early in startup (in `init.vim`) for plug-ins to be properly loaded.

Furthermore, many of the options set in those snippets are global (not buffer-local options), so while it's possible to set them in a filetype-specific script, it makes most sense to set them globally. (Setting those in `ftplugin/rust.vim` means they'll be set after the first Rust file is loaded, but they'll be applicable to *every* buffer opened after that, so in effect you'll have different behavior depending on whether a file is opened before or after a Rust file. So it makes more sense to load them in `init.vim` and having the behavior consistent.)

Similarly for the mappings, which are also global mappings. (The same effect of having them available everywhere *after* the first Rust file is loaded would apply.) Furthermore, the mappings are not Rust-specific, they're related to the LSP feature of NeoVim, so it makes sense to define these global mappings which will actually work with *any* language for which an LSP has been configured (which you should probably do if you work with other languages often.)

So, in short, just move that config to your `init.vim`. Hopefully, that's all you need to get everything to work as described in the guide.

Comment: Thank you but is it possible to say like only when a rust filetype is loaded execute these commands?

Comment: For some of them, yes, it's possible to modify them. For example, the mappings, you can make them local with `<buffer>` to put them in an ftplugin. Some settings can be local, so you can use `setlocal` there. Plug-ins need to be configured globally, but vim-plug has ways to only load them when a specific filetype or command is used (but that depends a lot on how the plug-in itself works...) Overall, I'd say it's not worth the effort. (Not sure what your motivation would be for that, there are no huge efficiency gains to get from it.)